# react Redux query string

Tags: react-redux

I have this route

```
<Route path="/Info/:id/:name/:type">
  <Info />
</Route>;
```

And this is Info Page

```
 export default class Info extends React.PureComponent {
  public state = {
  }
  componentDidMount () {

  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        this is info
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

How do i get query strings id, name and type to info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **useParams** from react-router-dom.
ie;

```
import React from "react";
import {
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";

export default class Info extends React.PureComponent {
  componentDidMount() {

  }

  render() {
    let { id, name, type } = useParams();
    return (
      <div>
        this is info
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `match` object of `react-router`.

```
Class Info extends React.PureComponent{
  render(){
    return(
      <h2>{this.props.match.params.id}</h2>
    )
  }
}
```

Read more on `match` object [here](http://%3Ch2%3E%7Bthis.props.match.params.id%7D%3C/h2%3E)

If you are using `react-router-dom 5.1`

Then you can use the `useParams`.

Read more on `useParams` [here](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/)